# Angular 1.5 Component: passing a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

Is it possible to passing a function to a component and call this function inside the component passing a parameter?

Example:

**List of posts**

```
<post-list posts="blog.posts"
           loading="blog.loadingPosts"
           get-post-url="blog.getPostUrl" 
           is-user-authenticate="blog.user">
</post-list>
```

**getPostUrl** is a function (*inside the container controller*):

```
const getPostUrl = (postId) => {
    const protocol = $location.protocol();
    const host = $location.host();
    const port = $location.port();

    return protocol + "://" + host + "" + (port !== 80 ? ":" + port : "") + "/blog/post/" + postId;
};
```

**List of posts: component**

```
const PostList = {
  "bindings": {
    "posts": "<",
    "loading": "<",
    "getPostUrl": "&", //Function getPostUrl
    "isUserAuthenticate": "<"
  },
  "template": `<div>
                <div class="col-md-9 text-center" data-ng-if="$ctrl.loading">
                  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9 posts" data-ng-if="!$ctrl.loading">
                  <div data-ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts">
                    <post creation-date="{{post.creationDate}}"
                          content="{{post.content}}"
                          post-url="{{$ctrl.getPostUrl(post.creationDate)}}"
                          is-user-authenticate="$ctrl.user">
                    </post>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>`,
   "transclude": false
};

 angular
  .module("blog")
  .component("postList", PostList);
```

In this line:

`post-url="{{$ctrl.getPostUrl(post.creationDate)}}"` I want to call the function passing a parameter and this function is returning a **string**.

*In **post component** (not PostList) the postUrl is a string attribute `@`*.

But... Is not working!

> angular.js:13550 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{$ctrl.getPostUrl(post.creationDate)}}
>   TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'blog' in 1459329888892
>   [Error Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7B$ctrl.getPostUrl(post.creationDate)%7D%7D&p1=TypeError:%20Cannot%20use%20%27in%27%20operator%20to%20search%20for%20%27blog%27%20in%201459329888892)

**Is it possible to do it? And how?**

*Thank you so much!*

Comment: You don't need the `{{ }}` for an `&` binding - see this section of the docs for a good example of how to achieve what you're looking to do: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture

Comment: But the return of this function is a string... `post-url` is a string. I want to call the function that return this string

Comment: I changed now... But now appears this error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'blog' `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call the function from inside a component and have it return a value then you need two-way binding:

```
"bindings": {
  "posts": "<",
  "loading": "<",
  "getPostUrl": "=", // <-- two-way binding
  "isUserAuthenticate": "<"
},
```

However, this is probably not very good idea. Consider *passing data to component* rather than making component request data from outside. This will make much better isolated component.

Answer (score 23):

You can pass functions to components, but you must define the function arguments as object with the correct arguments names as its keys.
example:

```
<post-list posts="blog.posts"
           loading="blog.loadingPosts"
           get-post-url="blog.getPostUrl(postId)" 
           is-user-authenticate="blog.user">
</post-list>

const PostList = {
 "bindings": {
  "posts": "<",
  "loading": "<",
  "getPostUrl": "&", //Function getPostUrl
  "isUserAuthenticate": "<"
 },
 "template": `<post creation-date="{{post.creationDate}}"
                      content="{{post.content}}"
                      post-url="{{$ctrl.getPostUrl({postId:post.creationDate})}}">
                </post>
```

Comment: this should really be the accepted solution as it is the proper function binding. Thanks for the tip. I didn't know the inner component had to pass the param back as a named object.

Answer (score 0):

**To return a value to the binding function you must pass it as a object literal.**     
self.selected({id: '42', firstname: 'Douglas', lastname: 'Adams'});

```
angular.module('webapp').component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'myComponent.html',

    bindings: {
        selected: '&'
    },
    controller: function () {
        var self = this;

        self.someEvent= function(){
            self.selected({id: '42', firstname: 'Douglas', lastname: 'Adams'});
        };
    }
});
```

**Afterwards you can access the object literal values by it's properties.**
id, firstname, lastname.
You can also pass additional parameters to the function. (myVariable)

```
<div>
    <span ng-init="myVariable='Universe'">
    <my-component selected="myFunction(id, firstname, lastname, myVariable)"></my-component>
</div>


$scope.myFunction = function(id, firstname, lastname, myVariable){
    console.log(id, firstname, lastname, myVariable);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Todd Motto's Standards, it is not suggested to use '=' instead try using '&' that is passing a method from parent to child component and calling the method in the child will trigger back in the parent. Let's take an example.

**Parent Component's template(HTML):**

```
<child take-me-to-school="$ctrl.searchBikeKeyAndStart>
```

**Child Component's controller:**

```
public someFunction = () => {
  this.takeMeToSchool();
}
```

Once the function is called from the child component's controller then the function mapped in the parent will get triggered.

**Parent Component's controller(HTML):**

```
public searchBikeKeyAndStart = () => {
  .....
}
```

When you want to pass an argument to the same function

**Parent Component's template(HTML):**

```
<child take-me-to-school="$ctrl.searchBikeKeyAndStart(**key**)>
```

**Child Component's controller:**

```
public someFunction = () => {
  this.takeMeToSchool({key: parameterValue});
}
```

Once the function is called from the child component's controller then the function mapped in the parent will get triggered.

**Parent Component's controller(HTML):**

```
public searchBikeKeyAndStart = (**key**) => {
  console.log(**key**) //will print the param passed
}
```